# why statistics methods of DataFrames return Series in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.13.1. This dataframe:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar", "qux"], "v": [1, 5.6, 50.5]})
a = a.set_index("a")
```

contains floats and their mean can be calculated with `.mean()`:

```
>>> a.mean()
v    19.033333
dtype: float64
>>> type(a.mean())
pandas.core.series.Series
```

however in pandas 0.13.1, this result is a `Series` and not a `float` - why is that? Is this new in pandas? IIRC it was not like this in older pandas.

Is this the correct way to get a float?

```
>>> a.mean()[0]
```

Comment: Is it a problem? It still does this in 0.14.0, probably 0.14.1 also.

Comment: @EdChum: I want to use ``mean()`` for downstream arithmetic calculations, so I want a float or integer or another value that makes sense for that. Series does not make sense for that. Do I use the ``[0]`` notation then?

Comment: You could do that or cast it `float(a.mean())` if you prefer

Comment: @user248237dfsf it absolutely does make sense for that you are calling that method on a dataframe, typically they have more than one column and usually a Series of means mapping to each column.  If you just want the mean of a Series which is 1d.  You can call     a['v'].mean() which does return a float

Comment: @ZJS: but in this case there's only one column, with all numerics. ``type(float(pandas.Series([5.5,6.6])))`` is invalid so the cast only makes sense for ``Series`` with one element.

Comment: @ZJS: your last comment not constructive. What's improper about my data storage? It's a dataframe with an index column and a numeric column. There's nothing improper about that. The cast was to EdChum

Comment: @user248237dfsf: Your right that was unclear.  The answer you marked as correct says, "If you want to treat your data as a single vector/array (i.e. any construct that would force your data to only have one column), the preferred way to represent that is as a Series."  -That is what I meant by you are storing your data improperly.  Not to say you cant store the data they way you did, but you should understand the difference between a DataFrame and a Series and choose properly.  In this example it probably would of been better to store "a" as a Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple columns, the Series from `df.mean()` contains a value for each column. So `a.mean()['v']` (get the 'v' value of the mean Series) or `a['v'].mean()` (take the mean of the Series 'v') would be the clearest ways of expressing what you're doing.

If you want to treat your data as a single vector/array (i.e. any construct that would force your data to only have one column), the preferred way to represent that is as a Series.

Alternatively, if you wanted the mean across all columns, you could do:

- `df.mean().mean()` (take the mean of each column, then give the mean of that)
- `df.mean(axis=0).mean()` (take the mean of each row, then give the mean of that)
- `df.as_matrix().mean()` (take the mean of the whole matrix [returned by pandas as a numpy matrix/2D array])
- `df.values.mean()` (same as above, may be faster but is a bit less clear [internal representation of pandas as a numpy array])